# Send bug report from azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to send emails to myself from azure with error and its details when server receives 500 error. 
I don't wont to receive messages that something happened (events works the same if I am not mistaken).
[image]

Is it possible? 
I know that I can find all errors with details in https://{site-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/websitelogs/#/detailederrors
But how to get text from new file I don't know.
Please help me.

**EDIT 1.**
I found streaming logs - Recent -> {site-name} -> tools -> streaming logs.
Here I can see all errors in real time. But I can't find where I can send these errors in my email.

Answer (score 0):

I think the web app dashboard does not support alerting directly. You should activate application insights on your web app and then you'll be able to configure email alert on failed request.

This page will help you with working with application insights alerts: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-alerts/

Hope this helps,

Julien